# How do I convert the the middle number coming from an presser in vb.net to asterisk in form of an account number

Tags: vb.net

Am working on a banking app and I want to send sms to the users and I want the account number to be in this form 2719**5849 and the account number is coming from a textbox

Comment: You should spend some time reading in the Help Center to learn what constitutes a reasonable question on this site.  Anything of the form *"I want to do X, tell me how"* does not qualify.

Comment: While my answer below might not provide the _exact_ code you are looking for, it should give you an idea. From there, you need to try writing something yourself and if you get stuck, then post _your_ code and what it outputs vs. what you are expecting. Then you can get specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying daShier's solution i got 1234**8910 for 12345678910
number 7 was removed

this should work for you on a button click and on any length size because it does not remove any chars

```
    Dim intg As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Length / 2
    Dim str As New List(Of String)
    Dim str2 As New List(Of String)
    For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
        str.Add(c)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
        If i <= intg AndAlso i >= intg - 2 Then
            str2.Add("*")
        Else
            str2.Add(str(i))
        End If
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = String.Join("", str2.ToArray())
```

changed to be 3 asterisk

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it change everything in the textbox to asterisk

Comment: you are doing something wrong, i post only what i test

Comment: https://ibb.co/xFNgBy0

Comment: plain text in textbox1, converted text will be in textbox2, all this code in a button with nothing else with this code, it will work

Comment: I have a code to do two asterisk I needed a way to perform three numbers to be asterisk and this your code is not converting any to asterisk

Comment: first of all my code works great and i sent you a picture as a POC
second of all your question was to convert 2 numbers in the middle to asterisk now you say you want three?? do you want me to send you the project or a video so you see how it's working?? create a new project, use my code, you are obviously putting something else with my code that's why it's not working or you still have another function working with it

Comment: Okay sorry for not putting that question in a right form can you make it three asterisk please

Comment: there you go i put the picture in the answer, i will make it 3 asterisk for you

Comment: made it 3 asterisk, don't forget to mark as answer

Comment: Where did you altered that made it to be three *

Comment: intg - 2 that was intg - 1

Comment: It work but the number to be shown as asterisk disappear in the second textbox I Inputed 2178456117 is displayed 2176117 the three to be displayed as asterisk disappeared

Comment: this is the whole project if you (or anyone else) still think it's not working, open the project and try it https://ufile.io/nwlqsrid

Comment: I don’t know what happened same code and only two numbers was asterisk but when I use your project it was three so I just copy and paste the code you used I observe it and it was the same and thanks I got what I was looking for I have tick it good

Comment: Thanks it had worked I just downloaded your project and copy the code and it work perfectly thanks

Comment: I don’t know if there is a way where I can shift the asterisk to the front like I have 2719472828 it started from 9 I want it to start from 4

Comment: Thanks I appreciate just the last one

Comment: the whole thing is in the "intg" as you can see i changed it to intg - 2 and made it 3 asterisk so play with that intg line inside that for loop to fit your needs

Comment: I tried it by changing the number but still yet it didn’t change the position of the asterisk

Comment: We can't just chat over the comments these threads are made so we answer the main question you're going to have to open a new thread, this thread is on hold too as off-topic, i will answer you once more, your string's length (10) is even so if you split in half it will be (5.5) what i did was that i made 4 5 and 6 as asterisks, if you understand how the code is working you can easily fix it yourself try `i <= intg + 1 AndAlso i >= intg - 1` or `i <= intg + 2 AndAlso i >= intg - 1` i bet one of them will work. Please open another thread if you have more than one question.

Comment: Thanks it’s working now I followed your last step

Comment: thanks it has worked to my satisfaction

Comment: Good to hear, glad it worked

Answer (score -1):

I would not convert each character in the middle to an `*` because it provides unnecessary information on the number of characters in the account number. Instead, I would just use a fixed number of `*` (two, as in your example) to represent all the middle characters:

**UPDATE:**
I added a check for the length, since I assume from your comments that you are trying this when the text in the textbox changes...

```vb
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim ObfuscatedAccount As String
        If TextBox1.Text.Length > 8 Then
            ObfuscatedAccount = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 4) &
         "**" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.Length - 4, 4)
            TextBox2.Text = ObfuscatedAccount
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: I tried it and outputted the result in a msg box to check the values it showed failed It did not work

Comment: What results did you get? One thing I didn't do was error check for strings less than 4 characters, but I assume that's not your issue at the moment.

Comment: No the number I entered into the text box was more than 4 it is 10 numbers and not strong so you should know and it showed failed what could have been the reason

Comment: Sorry, but your response was not too helpful: What do you mean "it showed failed"? What specifically did you see?

Comment: I used the code you showed me and try to display the result in a message box because the reason for this whole thing I want to use is so when the user make deposit it withdraw the full account number won’t show just like real life work and when I out put the result in message box it showed failed and I use a textbox to collect the user input which is the account number

Comment: Sorry it showed false not failed

Comment: An answer to a bad question is a bad answer.

Comment: I just ran the updated code to confirm it works exactly as written.

Comment: Not on the text change I want on the click of a button the number on the textbox should change and two digit should be change to asterisk

Comment: I believe you should have enough information now to code it the way you want. If you run into specific problems, then post what you tried and what results you got vs. what results you want.

Comment: Thanks it has worked I just corrected the code I put the message box at the wrong place thanks

Comment: The above code worked but I notice  after changing the account number two inside to asterisk it will add an addition number to the end making it 11 digit instead of the normal 10 that was typed in the textbox

Comment: 12345678910 would be 1234**8910 where did 567 go if replacing only 2 chars?